# COBRA eligibilty if employer changes providers at time of contract signing?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, insurance, cobra

I have a contract from July to June. I am a teacher.  At my meeting to discuss my position in September, I will probably be told that my hours are going to be reduced and I will no longer be eligible for company health care benefits – usually I would be able to go on COBRA.  The problem is that my company is changing health care providers on **July 1st** when my new contract would be in effect.

Can I get COBRA?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the fact that the company is changing health care providers should have no affect on your eligibility of COBRA - see these related questions:

> Q12: Under COBRA, what benefits must
>   be covered? Qualified beneficiaries
>   must be offered coverage identical to
>   that available to similarly situated
>   beneficiaries who are not receiving
>   COBRA coverage under the plan
>   (generally, the same coverage that the
>   qualified beneficiary had immediately
>   before qualifying for continuation
>   coverage). **A change in the benefits
>   under the plan for the active
>   employees will also apply to qualified
>   beneficiaries.** Qualified beneficiaries
>   must be allowed to make the same
>   choices given to non-COBRA
>   beneficiaries under the plan, such as
>   during periods of open enrollment by
>   the plan.

Here's more supporting evidence:

> Q24: Am I eligible for COBRA if my
>   company closed or went bankrupt and
>   there is no health plan? If there is
>   no longer a health plan, there is no
>   COBRA coverage available. If, however,
>   there is another plan offered by the
>   company, you may be covered under that
>   plan. Union members who are covered by
>   a collective bargaining agreement that
>   provides for a medical plan also may
>   be entitled to continued coverage.

From the [department of labor](http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/faqs/faq_consumer_cobra.HTML) website.

The reduction of hours should also be considered a qualifying event.

> Qualifying Events for Employees:
>
> - Voluntary or involuntary termination of employment for reasons
>     other than gross misconduct
> - Reduction in the number of hours of employment